# How do I print out the arguments from a function separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I built a function that accepts arguments into a list and then I just have to use the function to print out sandwich orders.

I tried just using the print function and using the function name as the thing I'm trying to print.

```
def sandwich_items(*items):
    sandwich_items = []
    sandwich_items.append(items)
    print("\nEnter what you want on your sandwich.")
    for item in items:
        print(" ...Putting " + item + " on your sandwich.")
    print("Your sandwich is ready!")

sandwich_items('tomatoes', 'lettuce', 'ham', 'salami')
sandwich_items('peanut butter', 'jelly')
sandwich_items('turkey breast', 'chicken breast', 'cheese')

#This is what I tried
print('I have made your ' + str(sandwich_items) + 'sandwich.')
```

When I tried printing it, I got an error message of:

```
 I have made your <function sandwich_items at 0x038295D0>sandwich.
```

Comment: This is not an error message but the default representation if you try to print a function object.

Comment: what are you expecting the output to  be? you are printing a string representation of the function

Comment: This is not the error, you are printing a function and not the call of the function i.e. you have called the function without (). also have different name for variable and function to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code :

```
def sandwich_items(*items):

  sandwich_items = []
  sandwich_items.append(items)
  print("\nEnter what you want on your sandwich.")
  for item in items:
       print(" ...Putting " + item + " on your sandwich.")

  print("Your sandwich is ready!")
  return ",".join(items )

sandw1 = sandwich_items('tomatoes', 'lettuce', 'ham', 'salami')
sandw2 = sandwich_items('peanut butter', 'jelly')
sandw3 = sandwich_items('turkey breast', 'chicken breast', 'cheese')

#This is what I tried
print('I have made your ' + sandw1 + ' sandwich.')
```

Output:

```
Enter what you want on your sandwich.
...Putting tomatoes on your sandwich.
...Putting lettuce on your sandwich.
...Putting ham on your sandwich.
...Putting salami on your sandwich.
Your sandwich is ready!

Enter what you want on your sandwich.
...Putting peanut butter on your sandwich.
...Putting jelly on your sandwich.
Your sandwich is ready!

Enter what you want on your sandwich.
...Putting turkey breast on your sandwich.
...Putting chicken breast on your sandwich.
...Putting cheese on your sandwich.
Your sandwich is ready!

I have made your tomatoes,lettuce,ham,salami sandwich.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the following way:

```
def add_items(lst):

     my_lst=[]
     print("\nEnter what you want on your sandwich.")
     for i in lst :
          my_lst.append(i)
          print(" ...Putting " + i + " on your sandwich.")
     print("Your sandwich is ready!")


lst = ['tomatoes', 'lettuce', 'ham', 'salami']

add_items(lst)
```